# Is it possible to retrieve the font scaling in Windows?

Tags: winapi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

Trying to change dimensions of my FMX form to emulate a 'FullScreen' mode, but using the Screen size backfires when a user has its settings with some bigger scaling, since the whole form becomes bigger than the screen.

How can I retrieve the scaling value so I can Size the form accordingly?

EDIT:
That's a little snippet that shows what was my intention with the question and how it was solved. Thank you for you time and help.

```
 procedure TMyForm.ApplyFullScreen;
var
  tmpEscale: Extended;
begin
  BorderStyle := TFmxFormBorderStyle.None;
  Left := 0;
  Top := 0;

  tmpEscala := USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI / GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(0), LOGPIXELSX);

  Height := Round(Screen.Height * tmpEscala);
  Width := Round(Screen.Width * tmpEscala);
end;
```

Comment: This is rather unclear. It would help if we knew exactly what your code was. Perhaps there is some simple mistake.

Comment: The screen dimensions are reported differently depending on whether your app is DPI-aware or not (requiring virtualized values).  Is your app DPI-aware?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question. GetDeviceCaps did it for me after I realized that the DPI info would change only after I have restarted my machine. @RemyLebeau my application was indeed DPI-aware, that was part of my confusion when setting dimmensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `EnumDisplaySettings` the resulting `DEVMODE` structure contains the DPI setting in the `dmYResolution` field.  Beware that passing `NULL` as the device name to `EnumDisplaySettings` will get the information only for one screen, on a multimonitor system you should enumerate all the display devices.

You can also call `GetDeviceCaps` on a device context, and query for `LOGPIXELSX` and `LOGPIXELSY`.

The DPI corresponds to font scaling as follows:

- 100% = 96 dpi
- 125% = 120 dpi
- 150% = 144 dpi
- 200% = 192 dpi

For more information, it would be good to refer to [the MSDN article on DPI-related APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dpi-related-apis-and-registry-settings)

Comment: It's not the dmYResolution field, but 'dmLogPixels' that has the DPI.

Answer (score 0):

I use such code:

```
function SystemFontSizeScale: Real; // 1.00 = standard 96 DPI
var
  DC : HDC; // WinApi.Windows
begin
  DC     := GETDC(0);
  Result := GetDeviceCaps(DC, LOGPIXELSX) / 96;
  ReleaseDC(0, DC);
end;
```